# Generate bi variate data for linear regression and k-NN

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I am reading generating data for linear regression and k-nearest neighbor in book "The Elements of Statistical Learning". Below are two scenario's mentioned in text

Remember that these are errors on the training data itself,
and we have not said where the constructed data came from. Consider the
two possible scenarios:

**Scenario 1: The training data in each class were generated from bi-variate Gaussian distributions with uncorrelated components and different means.

Scenario 2: The training data in each class came from a mixture of 10 low-variance Gaussian distributions, with individual means themselves distributed as Gaussian.**

[image]

My question is how can I write a program in python or in C++ to generate data for following

1. Scenario 1 mentioned above.
2. Scenario 2 mentioned above.
3. How to simulate data some what in between above two but closer to scenario 2.

Thanks for your time and help. This information will help me to try and understand Linear regression and k-NN.

Answer (score 0):

For Scenario 1: Able to generate by using following code. Looking in how to generate code for scenario 2.

```
mean_blue = [-1, 3]
cov = [[2, 0], [0, 2]]

x_blue_1, x_blue_2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_blue, cov, 50).T

mean_red = [2, 0]
cov = [[2, 0], [0, 2]]

x_red_1, x_red_2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean_red, cov, 50).T

plt.scatter(x_blue_1, x_blue_2)
plt.scatter(x_red_1, x_red_2)
```